# How do I keep the new structure of web imported data after refresh?

Tags: excel, web

I am creating an Excel database. I would like to import names, emails and job positions of all employees of a firm from the firm website.
 I choose Data->From Web and select the whole page, as it is the only possibility.

The page shows no table with data; just a long list of photos of employees with names, emails and job positions next to them

I import the data into my Excel spreadsheet: the format is very bad. So I begin cut and paste creating a column for "names", one for "email" and similarly for "job position". All other information is manually canceled.

I would like to refresh data keeping this new format. Unfortunately, every time I refresh the imported data using the "refresh all" button, they return to the original format.

How can I keep the new format of my web imported data, after refresh?

I thank you all for your support!

Kr,
A

Comment: If you have to edit it manually then I doubt there will be a simple method to do it. I don't seem to have import from the web as an option so cant help there, but there may be options to configure how the data is imported. If not you will need to create a macro that does the editing for you, or create a macro to scrape the website (not using the import feature)

Comment: Thanks NickSlash for your answer. Is it possible to create macros to scrape websites with Excel? Do I need some other program as interface between the web and Excel? Unfortunately I have not great programming skills...any other idea?

Comment: I found the import from web feature in the end, works fairly well. without seeing the web-page (doesn't need to be real data, so long as the underlying html is the same) you are taking the data from its difficult to see what might be causing the problem. Creating a scraper using VBA is less than ideal and wont allow "updating" unless you write that ability in.

Comment: Let us take the page http://www.hsbc.com/about-hsbc/leadership as example. I would like to have 2 columns in my spreadsheet, one with the names of directors and the other with their job title. Both columns are supposed to be periodically refreshed. Unfortunately all data return ot the original format after refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've put together an example that will extract the name and title from that page you specified and put them into sheet 1.

The code will only work providing the layout of the underlying html remains the same. It does not support updating of an existing list (anything on sheet 1 is removed prior to reading the list again)

To use this code you must place it in a new code module (not the worksheet or workbook sections) and you can run it either from the code editor or via the macros menu in the main excel window.

```
' Note: This code requires the following references to be loaded.
' Microsoft HTML Object Library (mshtml.tlb)
' Microsoft Internet Controls (ieframe.dll)
' To add a reference
' In the VBA Code Editor, in the Tools Menu click the References item
' Scroll through the list and ensure that the references are selected
' Press OK and your done.

Sub Scrape()
Dim Browser As InternetExplorer
Dim Document As HTMLDocument
Dim Element As IHTMLElement
Dim Elements As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim empName As String
Dim empTitle As String

Dim Sheet As Worksheet

    Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    Sheet.UsedRange.ClearContents ' Nuke the old list

    Set Browser = New InternetExplorer

    Browser.navigate "http://www.hsbc.com/about-hsbc/leadership"

    Do While Browser.Busy And Not Browser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set Document = Browser.Document

    Set Elements = Document.getElementsByClassName("profile-col1")

    For Each Element In Elements
        empName = Trim(Element.Children(1).Children(0).innerText)
        empTitle = Trim(Element.Children(1).Children(1).innerText)
        Sheet.Range("A1:B1").Insert xlShiftDown
        Sheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = empName
        Sheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = empTitle
        'Debug.Print "[  name] " & empName
        'Debug.Print "[ title] " & empTitle
    Next Element

    Set Browser = Nothing
    Set Elements = Nothing

End Sub
```